# Is there any way to access shared mailbox using python imaplib

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way to access shared mailbox using python imaplib,

I am trying to access the shared mailbox of my exchange server, but able to read the personal mail box, but not shared or functional mailbox.

I tried with result, data=mail.login('personal@domain.com\shared@domain.com','personalPassword') but its not seems to be working.

python 3.7

```
import imaplib
import email
mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-externl.xxxxxx.km')
mail.login("personalid.@ex.com\shared.@ex.com","xxxxxx")
mail.select("INBOX")
```

Comment: Hello, Did you manage to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Escape `\` slash.

```
mail.login("personalid.@ex.com\\\shared.@ex.com","xxxxxx")
```

Answer (score 0):

in my office365 shared mail box :

```
mail.login("personalid.@ex.com\\\shared.","xxxxxx")
```

the domain name isn't need!